# How to check if any of the div and input tag is empty in javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

the requirement is to check empty validation for multiple div and input tag in a single button click.

Html code

```
<div class=" droppable multipleAlertEmptyCheck"></div>
<input type="text" class="multipleAlertEmptyCheck">
<div class=" droppable multipleAlertEmptyCheck"></div>
<input type="text" class="multipleAlertEmptyCheck">
```

Js Code

```
$(document).on('click','#multipleAlertSubmit', function(){
    var actval = $(".multipleAlertEmptyCheck");
    var actcount = actval.length;
    for(var i = 0; i<=actcount-1; i++){     
     if(actval[i].value == '' || actval[i].textContent == ''){
         document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Fill all fields";
         return false;
    }else{   
         document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="";
    } 
    }
```

Comment: you need to add the whole code because this snippet shows   that you use an array ? why you used for loop ?

Comment: Well, what goes wrong with the current code? What is your question?

Comment: Notice, that one of the conditions is always true, hence the if is always passed, and the validation is doomed to fail no matter what the values are. A hackish "single shot" would be `if (+!!(actval[i].textContent) + +!!(actval[i].value) < 1) {...}`.

Comment: See the [hack in action](https://jsfiddle.net/0cd1kjrL/).

Comment: @Mooga my requirement  is to check empty validation for multiple div and input tags in a single  button click and if anyone is empty I need to show an error message inside a label(while drag and drop dropping I am adding data in to div and input tag user enters),For loop i used to navigate through all the elements where ever class presents

Comment: @Teemu i tried if (+!!(actval[i].textContent) + +!!(actval[i].value) < 1) but empty valiation not happening for div

Comment: It surely validates also _empty_ divs, see the fiddle I've linked above. Empty a div and run the fiddle, then click Check button. If there's white-space in a div (new-line for example), then there's is some content, though.

Comment: To tackle the white-space use `if (!(actval[i].value || actval[i].textContent).trim()) {...}`, [see it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/0cd1kjrL/1/).

Answer (score 1):

```js
function logEmptyElements ( $elements ) {
  //find the input elements that do not have a value
  var $emptyInputs = $elements.filter(':input').filter(function(){
      return !this.value.trim();
  });
  //find the non inputs that do not have inner html
  var $emptyDivs = $elements.not(':input').filter(function(){
      return !this.innerHTML.trim();
  });
  
  console.log(
    $emptyInputs.add($emptyDivs).get()
  );
}

logEmptyElements( $('.multipleAlertEmptyCheck1') );
logEmptyElements( $('.multipleAlertEmptyCheck2') );
logEmptyElements( $('.multipleAlertEmptyCheck3') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="droppable multipleAlertEmptyCheck1"></div>
<input type="text" class="multipleAlertEmptyCheck1">
<div class="droppable multipleAlertEmptyCheck1"></div>
<input type="text" class="multipleAlertEmptyCheck1">

<div class="droppable multipleAlertEmptyCheck2">A</div>
<input type="text" class="multipleAlertEmptyCheck2" value="1">
<div class="droppable multipleAlertEmptyCheck2"></div>
<input type="text" class="multipleAlertEmptyCheck2">

<div class="droppable multipleAlertEmptyCheck3">A</div>
<input type="text" class="multipleAlertEmptyCheck3" value="1">
<div class="droppable multipleAlertEmptyCheck3">B</div>
<input type="text" class="multipleAlertEmptyCheck3" value="2">
```

Comment: Thank all for your help, I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing that you can go for

```
var actval = $(".multipleAlertEmptyCheck");
if(actval.val() === '' || actval.text() === '') {
//do something 
}
```

Comment: Div tags do not have a "value"

Comment: Divs don't have a val, they do have a text() though

Comment: using drag and drop functionality adding html  to div eg:- $(this).html(CombinedValue);

Comment: Looks like we got there :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/au0qdtj1/1/  Given that the OP wants to test that *any* of the inputs are not set, this solution is incomplete.

Comment: It's not working. My requirement is that to check empty in both div and input tag

Comment: the reason what I think it is not working is because the input tag is empty and the JS loads before HTML so your  required js should be called by an event EX.= http://jsfiddle.net/au0qdtj1/8/

Comment: Nope, the function is called on button click.

Comment: @Teemu and Mangy thank you very much for your support,I solved this using different class name for div and input tag.